# ExtJS 4 group by one column in store, total another

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, extjs

I have a store of data representing bank deposits.  The data looks something like this:

```
{ account : 'a', amount : 5 },
{ account : 'a', amount : 15 },
{ account : 'b', amount : 7 },
{ account : 'b', amount : 3 },
{ account : 'c', amount : 12 },
```

I would like to display this data in a grid that groups by account and totals amount. I do not want to display the original data. Just the grouped data.

```
Account    Total Amount
a           20
b           10
c           12
```

If this were a sql database the query would be along these lines:

select account, sum( amount ) from tbl group by account;

is this possible in extjs without doing it manually? I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have called this method on my store:

```
store.group('account');
```

And my column in my grid panel that should display the total looks like this:

```
{
  :text => 'Total Amount',
  :dataIndex => 'amount',
  :summaryType => 'sum',
},
```

I know the group is doing something because I can change the order from ASC to DESC and the grid displays it differently. But for now the grid just displays all of the rows with no grouping.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that Ext JS doesn't have support for displaying data exactly as you want.

You can use `Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary` feature

- documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary

Or you can get grouped data from grouped store by

> store.getGroups()

and process them manually.

- documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getGroups